# I can't access contents of table (table data)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am working on C# .net efc and a newbie. By following a tutorial, I am trying to connect database to my entities (models) but I can't view them like he does in tutorial. I am using migrations and DbContext. The issue is he is using an older version of .net and I am using new version. pls check what am I doing wrong?

```
//Startup.cs
//using eTickets.Data;
using eTickets3.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace eTickets3
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Db Context
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>();
            //services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>
              //  (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString")));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseSession();

            //Authentication & Authorization
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Movies}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            //database seeding
            //AppDbInitializer.Seed(app);
        }
    }
}

//AppDbContext
using eTickets3.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace eTickets3.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Actor_Movie>().HasKey(am => new
            {
                am.ActorId,
                am.MovieId
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Actor_Movie>()
                .HasOne(m => m.Movie).WithMany(am => am.Actors_Movies)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.MovieId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Actor_Movie>()
                .HasOne(m => m.Actor).WithMany(am => am.Actors_Movies)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.ActorId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Actor>()
                .HasData(
                new Actor
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    FullName = "Actor 2",
                    Bio = "This is the Bio of the first actor",
                    ProfilePictureURL = "http://dotnethow.net/images/actors/actor-1.jpeg"
                },

                new Actor
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    FullName = "Actor 3",
                    Bio = "This is the Bio of the first actor",
                    ProfilePictureURL = "http://dotnethow.net/images/actors/actor-1.jpeg"
                },

                new Actor
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    FullName = "Actor 1",
                    Bio = "This is the Bio of the first actor",
                    ProfilePictureURL = "http://dotnethow.net/images/actors/actor-1.jpeg"
                });
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Actor_Movie> Actors_Movies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cinema> Cinemas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Producer> Producers { get; set; }
    }
}
//Sample AppDbContext //I added this because I was unable to do migration and I checked from internet
using eTickets3.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace eTickets3.Data
{
    public class SampleAppDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>
    {
        public AppDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString");
            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

            return new AppDbContext(builder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumbly you're following a guide for .NET "Framework". where as you're using .NET "Core". There are (some significant) difference between the 2; ideally if you are using .NET Core you should be following a .NET Core tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the tutorial are you following? You need to pay attention that `.net 4.x` version is `.net framework`, `.net 3.x`, `.net 5.0` and later are `.net core`, the two are different frameworks, so the documents cannot be used universally.

Judging by your code, you should be using .net 3.1 or 5.0. You can do it by following the steps below.

Install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` Nuget Packages:

[image]

Add your connection string in appsettings.json file, for example:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=eTickets3;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

Models(Take `Actor`, `Movie` and `Actor_Movie` as an example):

```
public class Actor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePictureURL { get; set; }
    public List<Actor_Movie> Actors_Movies { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public List<Actor_Movie> Actors_Movies { get; set; }

}

public class Actor_Movie
{
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public Actor Actor { get; set; }
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
}
```

AppDbContext:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Actor_Movie>().HasKey(am => new
        {
            am.ActorId,
            am.MovieId
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Actor_Movie>()
            .HasOne(m => m.Movie).WithMany(am => am.Actors_Movies)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.MovieId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Actor_Movie>()
            .HasOne(m => m.Actor).WithMany(am => am.Actors_Movies)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.ActorId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Actor>()
            .HasData(
            new Actor
            {
                Id = 1,
                FullName = "Actor 2",
                Bio = "This is the Bio of the first actor",
                ProfilePictureURL = "http://dotnethow.net/images/actors/actor-1.jpeg"
            },

            new Actor
            {
                Id = 2,
                FullName = "Actor 3",
                Bio = "This is the Bio of the first actor",
                ProfilePictureURL = "http://dotnethow.net/images/actors/actor-1.jpeg"
            },

            new Actor
            {
                Id = 3,
                FullName = "Actor 1",
                Bio = "This is the Bio of the first actor",
                ProfilePictureURL = "http://dotnethow.net/images/actors/actor-1.jpeg"
            });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Actor_Movie> Actors_Movies { get; set; }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString")));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can choose to migrate and update the database using command line, or create the database manually:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```

[image]

You can see the generated tables in the database:

[image]

Then you can inject the `AppDbContext` in the controller and operate on the database:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var actor = _context.Actors.ToList();
        return View();
    }
}
```

[image]

You can check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) for more information.